# How to include conditional := reference or set() in data.table

Tags: r, set, data.table, conditional-statements

New to R and working my way through DataCamp to better understand Data Tables.   Trying to apply := and set on a large data set to aggregate.
Wondering if someone can give me with a pointer on including conditionals into a := or set() for data tables.   I have a large 10 million row 20+ column datatable where I am trying to group by an ID and period (using setkey), testing row i-1 against i for column name "period" to provide a categorical output 0 or 1 in the "flag" column.

I've tried:

```
for(i in 1:200) 
  set(DT, i, .(period[i]-period[i-1]<=1, period[i]-period[i-1]>1), flag = .(0,1))
# error is unused argument flag=.(0,1)
```

I'm probably mixing up := and set and base R.  I haven't seen where examples compare one row to another and include the index in the call to provide two different outputs.

[image]

Comment: Last I checked `.()` notation doesn't work outside of `DT[...]` and so won't work inside `set(...)`.

Comment: Anyway, if it's just "flag if it changed by more than one", then `DT[, flag := period - shift(period, fill=period[1L]) >= 1L, by=ID]` You could wrap in as.integer of you want 1/0 instead of true/false. By the way, next time please provide a reproducible example. See https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Support

Comment: Thanks Frank.  As I experiment with your code I'm not sure I understand the shift.   Is it incremented forward one row with the shift fill.  I'm not quite getting the response I'm looking for yet but probably struggling to explain.   I need to assume that when grouped by ID that the first flag is 0 and then test the next row (per group) to see if it exceeds a difference of 1.  If so,  flag should be 1 else 0.  Question on the integer wrap.  Is this only wrapped on flag or j in the call out?  thanks again

Comment: I suggest you try reading `?shift` and going through the examples there to figure out if it works for you.

Comment: Got it Frank.   Thanks for the lead on this one.  Shift got me in the game.  The challenge was ensuring that the column type was clearly coerced initially.  Thanks again.  I'll adjust my request with clearer code availability next time.